# How to make mock data for testing in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mocking

I am testing an event file in my flutter project.

```dart
  group('ClientCreateClient', () {
    test('supports comparisons', () {
      expect( ClientCreateClient(1, PrivateClientModel(1, List<TestModel>.filled(2, TestModel())) ),  ClientCreateClient(1, PrivateClientModel(1, List<TestModel>.filled(2, TestModel()))));
    });
  });
```

in the above code I need to provide a privateClientModel which has an id and a List as it's parameters.
How can I create a mock list to achieve this?
The above code fails the test and gives me this error

```
Expected: ClientCreateClient:<ClientCreateClient(1, Instance of 'PrivateClientModel')>
  Actual: ClientCreateClient:<ClientCreateClient(1, Instance of 'PrivateClientModel')>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter test failure, unit test expected and actual state object are the same but still fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67430793/flutter-test-failure-unit-test-expected-and-actual-state-object-are-the-same-bu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as stated in the above comments I searched those links and it looks like I needed to extend equatable with those classes and it worked out for me.